# Find the value of $k-2l+m$, $\text{f(x)} = lx^2+kx+m, \quad \quad \text{if}\, x>1\\ \quad\quad =kx^2+l, \quad \quad\quad \text{if}\, x\leq1$,

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Find the value of $k-2l+m$, $\text{f(x)} = lx^2+kx+m, \quad \quad \text{if}\, x>1\\ \quad\quad =kx^2+l, \quad \quad\quad \text{if}\, x\leq1$.

$f$ is continuous and differentiable at $x=1$. While solving the question, I equated the left hand limit and right hand limit at 1 equal to $f(1)$ because $f$ is continuous and got $k+l=l+k+m=k+l$ which helped me get $m=0$. I also differentiated $f$ at 1 using the first principle of differentiation to get $f'(1)=2l+k$. I am having trouble progressing further because other similar types of questions usually involve variables only in one part of the expression. It would be helpful to get clarity on this point.
Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please put the question in the main body not just the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $f$ is continuous at $x=1$, $l + k + m = k + l \Rightarrow m = 0$

Because $f$ is also differentiable at $x=1$,
\begin{align}
 L = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}
\end{align}
exists.
\begin{align}
\tag{1}
 L_-\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{k(1+h)^2+l-k-l}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{2kh+kh^2}{h} = 2k
\newline
\tag{2}
 L_+=\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{l(1+h)^2+k+kh-k-l}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{2lh+lh^2+kh}{h} = 2l + k 
\end{align}
For the limit $L$ to exist, $L_- = L_+ \Rightarrow 2k = 2l+k \Rightarrow k = 2l$

Then, $k-2l+m = 2l - 2l + 0 = 0$

Comment: Thank you so much!